# Bug Tracking Tools that Push to Jira

Tags: jira, bug-tracking, defects

Our dev team uses Jira for our user stories. However, our clients don't have access to our Jira account. I am looking for a bug tracking tool that the clients can access and can sync/push the bugs they log into Jira. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Have you used Jira Service Desk?

Comment: That would be a good option. However, our clients wouldn't have access to our Jira account which is what led me to seek outside tools.

Comment: You may use Jira service desk cloud for this purpose (its free for upto 10 users)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good option with the tool ReqTest. Looks like there is a plugin for Jira that allows you to sync issues.